# Hide cookies from request or response header

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, tomcat, tomcat5.5

I want hide default cookie value from request and response header so that any request capturing tools don't show cookie value. i tried various blogs in which they are saying about secure set to true but it is for setting cookig value for https. But i wan't to hide cookie information from request or response header.

I am using jdk 1.5, servlet 2.4 and tomcat 5.35

Comment: What do you mean by hiding request or response header?

Comment: Your question doesn't make any sense. That's the only place to cookie goes, so if you "hide it" from there, it doesn't exist at all.

Answer (score 0):

Cookies are the way information are passed back and forth. You cannot hide them from view.

You could try to work via HTTPS and use the secure-tag. Secure-Cookies will only be handled via HTTPS, and will not be plaintext for any capturing tool to see. If HTTPS is no option, then you're out of luck I guess.